# Checking unique constraint in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-data

I need to validate for unique constraint. Let's say I have validator like this:

```
class Validator {

  Repository repository; // spring data jpa interface

 boolean isUnique(Product p){
  if(repository.exists(p))
    return false;
  }
}

class SomeService {

  Repository repository; // spring data jpa interface
    Validator v;

 void save(Product p){
   if(v.isUnique(p))
      repository.save(p)
 }
}
```

The question is: what happens when many threads with the same argument calls SomeService.save(Product p) method? Let's say 10 threads returns true on isUnique() and then 10 threads are saving my entity. If it has unique-constrain on database, it will throw an exception right? To avoid that I have to set locking as pessimistic or synchronize code? But if I have that constraint on database layer anyway, maybe it's just better to handle unique_constrain exception and removing isUnique method from my Validator? How do you think?